# After "with automatic weights", nose became weird

Tags: artifacts

After "with automatic weights", nose became weird.

Why is this happening?

Here's a video that shows the problem: https://youtu.be/1izcoGULxDo

Here's the .blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3u3wcv485pujeaz/2b_09_af%20generate%20rig.blend?dl=0

[image]

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXnqR.jpg) with the supplied file. Possibly a hidden object which shows in the render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks like a mesh deformation. (Its hard to see in the video :-D )

1. I don't do much rigging, but under amateur in properties, go to display and check axis.
   Check that the axis is Z-up on the nasal bones. 
   If it is not, rotate it and re-parent it with automatic weights.
2. Check that in edit mode the normals are correct along. They shouldn't be though due to your correct texturing.
3. Check all scales have been applied to the objects. (Object --> Apply --> Scale) It can sometimes deform meshes, particularly when sculpting and rigging.

Other than that, I have no clue.

All the best of luck and hope I helped,

BFB

EDIT: I took a look at your model and I seem to be right. I turned on axes in the amateur pannel. The bones going around the outside of your nostrils are at a -90˚ roll. Set it to 0.

Comment: Could you download the blend file supplied by the asker and verify that one of your methods solves the problem?

Comment: Thanks Bigfoot Blondy. Which bone did you tell me?
https://youtu.be/SwzZyv-CdMc

Comment: nose.R.001 and nose.L.001